# Populating Checkboxes on Rails from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just starting to learn about Rails (ver. 3), and I am trying to create a user registration form with checkbox options for their interests, which may be 0 or more selections. I generated a User scaffold, and an interest model. I seeded the interests table in Postgresql with data:

```
                                 Table "public.interests"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers
------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('interests_id_seq'::regclass)
 interest   | character varying(40)       |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "interests_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The view has:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="interest_ids[]">Interests:</label>
    <% for interest in Interest.find(:all) do %>
      <br><%= check_box_tag 'interest_ids[]', interest.id,
              @model.interest_ids.include?(interest.id) %>
      <%= interest.name.humanize %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

(based on [Checkboxes on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621340/checkboxes-on-rails))

The model interest.rb has:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The users controller users_controller.rb has:

```
 def new
  @user = User.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
  end
end
```

When I view the page I get:

```
undefined method `interest_ids' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is @model supposed to be?  I don't see it defined anywhere.  It looks like maybe it should be @user instead?  Another issue is that you're using HABTM, where its preferable to use Has Many Through.

Comment: Somequestions:

1. The view you have shown is for which controller? I suppose it is for InterestsController.2
. Your variable `@model` should be of which type? In the view, the `@model` gets the message `interest_ids`, and if the `@model` is not filled, it is `nil` automatically. That should explain the error message. Some model class has to implement `interest_ids`.

Comment: This bit `@model.interest_ids.include?(interest.id) %>` helped me with my problem! My form was not reloading the settings or persisting them properly. So, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Railscast on this? http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

At first glance, if these checkboxes are part of your use create or edit form, I'd think the tag should be:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'user[interest_ids][]', interest.id, @model.interest_ids.include?(interest.id)%>
```